# Extract numpy diagonal of specifed array position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array created with `np.zeros((10,10))`.
There are 1-s randomly in the array e.g.:

```
arr[2][4] = 1
arr[3][5] = 1
arr[4][6] = 1
```

resulting in:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I am given a position in the array e.g.: `arr[2][4]`.
How do I extract both diagonals(top left to bottom right and top right to bottom left) using Numpy methods, taking bounds into calculation.
Here is a complete example of what I want to achive:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((10,10))
arr[2][4] = 1
arr[3][5] = 1
arr[4][6] = 1

def extract_diags(arr, position):
   # some numpy magic here
   return diags

topl_bottomr_diag, topr_bottoml_diag = extract_diags(arr, (2,4))


print(topl_bottomr_diag)
>>> (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
print(topr_bottoml_diag)
>>> (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def extract_diags(arr, position):
   return np.diag(arr, position[1]-position[0]), np.diag(arr[::-1,:], position[1]+position[0]-len(arr)+1)
```

Example

```py
M=np.arange(64).reshape(-1,8) # Easier to verify result than with almost all 0. 
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
#       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
#       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
#       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
#       [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
#       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
#       [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
#       [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]])


extract_diags(M, (2,4)) # M[2,4]=20
# (array([ 2, 11, 20, 29, 38, 47]), array([48, 41, 34, 27, 20, 13,  6]))
```

### Explanation

`np.diag(M, offset)` is the diagonal of matrix M, if offset=0, and with some shifting (positive over the diagonal, negative under) if specified.
So, any `M[i,i]` is on the diagonal, hence offset=i-i=0. Any `M[i,i+1]` is on the diagonal just over, hence offset=i+1-i=1. Any `M[i,i+k]` is on a diagonal k places over the main one, hence offset=i+k-i=k. And generally speaking, offset for `M[i,j]` is j-i.

For the other diagonal, it is the same, with matrix `M[::-1]`, taking into account that element at position `[i,j]` in M is at position `[len(M)-1-i,j]` in `M[::-1]`. Hence offset in `M[::-1]` of `j-(len(M)-1-i)` = `j+i-len(M)+1`

Comment: Great answer! 
What if my matrix is really big, say 2000x2000 and I only want to extract a part of the matrix like 4 elements each diagonal way, taking bounds into consideration?

Comment: @Showertime 2000×2000 is not that big (well, for a matrix it is quite big, if you want to invert it, find its eigenvectors, or things like that. But for an array, as it is here... the diagonal we extract is, at most, 2000 elements). So that would not be really a computational problem at least. That being said, if, for some other reason you want to restrict the returned value, it is quite easy. Consider the fact that the element `[i,j]` is either the ith or the jth (whatever come first) of its diagonal (just draw it visually: the diagonal starts either at the top line, or at the leftest column)

Comment: @Showertime So, you know your element is at `min(i,j)` of the currently returned diagonal. If you want a window w=4 around that, just extract `res[min(i,j)-w:min(i,j)+w+1]`. And because w could be too big, clip it. So `res[np.clip(min(i,j)-w,0,len(M)-1), np.clip(min(i,j)+w+1, 0, len(M)-1)]`. With `res` being the 1st diagonal returned

Comment: @Showertime For the other diagonal, likewise, but in `M[::-1]`. And in `M[::-1]`, element is at position `[len(M)-i-1, j]` in the flipped matrix. So at position `min(len(M)-i-1, j)` of its diagonal.

Comment: @Showertime You could wonder if that is optimal (to extract the whole diagonal, and then drop everything but a few values from it). But I think it is. Trying to pick up, one by one, in pure python the values is probably costier tha those numpy operations. If size could go to the millions, then, after a while O(n), even vectorized O(n) costs more than O(4) (cost of your partial extraction). But, and that is why I insist on the fact that, as an array dimension, 2000 is not that much: at 2000 we are probably not yet at the situation "numpy O(n) > pure python O(4)"

Comment: @Showertime (I was just about to edit my answer, to replace `diag` by some `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(M.ravel()[j-i:], shape=(len(M)-(j-i),), strides=(sum(M.strides),))`. Which doesn't really create a new vector containing the diagonal, but just plays with how the array is indexed to create an array that iterates along diagonal. So doing that for a 8x8 matrix cost exactly the same as for a 1000000x1000000 matrix: it is O(1), not O(n), since it is just strides and index manipulation

Comment: @Showertime But whle trying to exhibit an experiment to show the difference (with this way of extracting the diagonal, if matrix change, then the content of the extracted diagonal also change, since it is not a copy but a view), I realized that is is also the case for `np.diag`!

Comment: @Showertime said otherwise, `np.diag` is probably working exactly like my `as_strided` hack. And, anyway, is just a view. So, like `as_strided` costs O(1) not O(n). So, my point is: it doesn't matter that diagonals contain 8 or 2000 elements. It is for free anyway. It is only what you do with those elements that may cost. So, my first comment (just extract a subarray of the result) is ok, even without the "2000 is not that much argument".

Comment: @Showertime I said "2000 is not enough so that numpy O(n) > pure python O(4)". But that wasn't even necessary. It is "numpy O(1) vs pure python O(1)" anyway. So even if you had a 1 billion×1 billion matrix extracting the 1 billion long diagonal and then a subarray of length 4 has a cost proportional to only 4, not 1 billion.